# Javascript Alexa function returns [object Object] when taking user input

Tags: javascript, alexa-skills-kit

I have a random number function in my Alexa skill which uses the AMAZON.NUMBER slot type, intent schema shown below.

```
"slots": [
        {
          "name": "NumOne",
          "type": "AMAZON.NUMBER"
        },
        {
          "name": "NumTwo",
          "type": "AMAZON.NUMBER"
        }
      ],
```

I get the numbers the user wants to use and put them into Num1 and Num2 respectively, as shown in my function below.

```
    var Num1 = this.event.request.intent.slots.NumOne;
    var Num2 = this.event.request.intent.slots.NumTwo;

    var result = Math.floor(Math.random() * (Num2 - Num1) + Num1);

    // Create speech output
    //var speechOutput = "The random number is: " + result;
    var speechOutput = Num1 + Num2;
    var cardTitle = "Random Number between " + Num1 + "and " + Num2;
    //response.tellWithCard(speechOutput, cardTitle, speechOutput);
    this.emit(':tell', speechOutput, cardTitle, speechOutput);
```

However when I print Num1 and Num2 they both appear as [object Object] which means that I can't do any calculations with them as the result will always be NaN.

```
{
  "version": "1.0",
  "response": {
    "shouldEndSession": true,
    "outputSpeech": {
      "type": "SSML",
      "ssml": "<speak> [object Object][object Object] </speak>"
    }
  },
  "sessionAttributes": {}
}
```

Is there anyway to fix this so Num1 and Num2 have number values?

Comment: You can't convert an object to a number. You will have to see if those objects contain numbers and extract them. Also, slots is an array and you appear to be trying to access it by *name*? None of this makes sense...

Comment: Please add a log to get event json and share it. Before providing a solution want to see the Json structure.

Comment: the response should be **this.emit(':tell', speechOutput)**, not what you have wriiten.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I left it for a while and had a think about the problem and found that all I needed to do was change

```
var Num1 = this.event.request.intent.slots.NumOne;
```

to

```
var Num1 = this.event.request.intent.slots.NumOne.value;
```

This got the value from the slot and not just the slot type (which is object hence why object Object was being returned).